# True transpose of data does not really exist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have searched and tried various code methods for days now, to accomplish what I need and I am almost convinced that no on has done this yet. Please help someone (Not to sound desperate, but I will name my next child after you)...

I have a grid I bind to a typical SQL query.
And it displays like this:

> MonthYearText | BegInventory | Refunds | BrokenItems | EndingInventory | etc |
>   2013-01                 |          120             |        10       |              5             |              125                |  22  |
>   2013-02                |          100             |          5       |             2             |              105                |  11  |
>   2013-03                |            66             |          2        |             1             |                67                 |   5  |

I need this:

MonthYearText    | 2013-01 | 2013-02 | 2013-03 | etc
BegInventory       |     120      |     100      |      66       |  ##
Refunds                   |        10      |           5      |         2       |  ##
BrokenItems         |           5      |           2     |          1      |  ##
EndingInventory |     125     |      105      |       67     |  ##
etc                               |        22      |         11     |         5       |  ##

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your coding approaches please ? Not sure why you think nobody has ever done this yet.. all you're doing is translating the axes, have you tried doing this at SQL level instead of code ? Would be easier IMO - [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server-2008)

(Assuming you're using SQL Server, apologies if you're using something else but similar techniques are available in Oracle, MySQL, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you "Goat CO" and "sh1rts" for the quick replies. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. I am fairly new to SQL code. The problem I have is PIVOT is not a true transpose. It wants to transpose on a column and aggregate that column with a function. I looked at PIVOT, UNPIVOT and the CASE statement solutions and in the end I READ() the query into a C# DataTable() and transposed the data through a method and into a new DataTable().
Ends up being a good solution for what I need. Thanks again guys I appreciate your time!